# Read route values in asp.net core 1.0.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware, asp.net-core-localization

I want to implement a nice way of localization and need help to figure out how to readout route parameters. First of all i implemented the Localization as follows:

In **Startup.cs**

```
// Configure supported cultures and localization options
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
  var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("de-DE") };
  options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US", "en-US");

  options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
  options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

  options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
  {
    var cultureInfo = options.DefaultRequestCulture.Culture;

    string contextRequestUrlPath = context.Request.Path.ToString();
    foreach (var c in supportedCultures)
      if (contextRequestUrlPath.Contains(c.ToString())) cultureInfo = c;

    return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(cultureInfo.ToString()));
  }));
});
```

For every request my **CustomRequestCultureProvider** checks via string.Contains() if a culture information is inside and updates the **ProviderCultureResult**.

And iam routing like that:

```
app.UseMvc(
  routes => { routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); });
```

Is there a way to readout the **culture** template element from a current route? I need to check this on several points in my project. Also in a view i want to have the possibility to readout route values instead of checking the **context.Request.Path** string.

Answer (score 0):

Try anywhere in the controller:

```
var requestCultureFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
var culture = requestCultureFeature.RequestCulture.Culture;
```